# Can't grab a specific portion of text out of some html elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've created a script in python to parse the address out of some html elements. When I execute my script, I get `title`, `address` and `phone` number from the elements whereas my intention is to get only the ***address***. If I used `next_sibling`, I could get only the first portion of the address seperated by br tag and that is why I skipped that approach.

How can I get only the address and nothing else from the below snippet?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmldoc = """
<div class="search-article-title-description">
    <div class="search-article-title">
      <a href="https://www.pga.com/pgapro/info/999918438?atrack=pgapro%3Anone&amp;seapos=result%3A1%3AJeff%20S%20Swangim%2C%20PGA&amp;page=1">Jeff S Swangim, PGA</a>
      <div class="search-article-protitle">
        Assistant Professional
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-article-address">
      <div class="search-instructor-course">
        Lake Toxaway Country Club
      </div>
      4366 W Club Blvd<br>Lake Toxaway, NC  28747-8538<br> 
      <div class="spotlightphone_num">
        (828) 966-4661
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldoc,"lxml")
address = soup.select_one(".search-article-address").get_text(strip=True)
print(address)
```

What I'm getting right now:

```
Lake Toxaway Country Club4366 W Club BlvdLake Toxaway, NC  28747-8538(828) 966-4661
```

My expected output:

```
4366 W Club BlvdLake Toxaway, NC  28747-8538
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can think of is using `.extract()` function to kick out the portion you are not interested in. If we can ignore the content of this classes `search-instructor-course` and `spotlightphone_num` then the remain portion is the desired one.

The following script should give us the address:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmldoc = """
<div class="search-article-title-description">
    <div class="search-article-title">
      <a href="https://www.pga.com/pgapro/info/999918438?atrack=pgapro%3Anone&amp;seapos=result%3A1%3AJeff%20S%20Swangim%2C%20PGA&amp;page=1">Jeff S Swangim, PGA</a>
      <div class="search-article-protitle">
        Assistant Professional
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-article-address">
      <div class="search-instructor-course">
        Lake Toxaway Country Club
      </div>
      4366 W Club Blvd<br>Lake Toxaway, NC  28747-8538<br> 
      <div class="spotlightphone_num">
        (828) 966-4661
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldoc,"lxml")
[item.extract() for item in soup.find_all(class_=["search-instructor-course","spotlightphone_num"])]
address = soup.select_one(".search-article-address").get_text(strip=True)
print(address)
```

Answer (score 1):

You use xpath expression here and lxml. You can still pass your HTML content to this.

```
from lxml import html

h = '''
<div class="search-article-title-description">
    <div class="search-article-title">
      <a href="https://www.pga.com/pgapro/info/999918438?atrack=pgapro%3Anone&amp;seapos=result%3A1%3AJeff%20S%20Swangim%2C%20PGA&amp;page=1">Jeff S Swangim, PGA</a>
      <div class="search-article-protitle">
        Assistant Professional
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-article-address">
      <div class="search-instructor-course">
        Lake Toxaway Country Club
      </div>
      4366 W Club Blvd<br>Lake Toxaway, NC  28747-8538<br> 
      <div class="spotlightphone_num">
        (828) 966-4661
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

'''

tree = html.fromstring(h)
links = [link.strip() for link in tree.xpath("//div[@class='search-article-address']/br/preceding-sibling::text()[1]")]
print(' '.join(links))
```

Output:

[image]

Or, more simply, thanks to @SIM, just:

```
print(' '.join(tree.xpath("//div[@class='search-article-address']/text()")))
```

Comment: @SIM Thanks. Still getting to grips with all this. +

Answer (score 0):

there might be a more elegant way, but you're correct to be looking to use `.next_sibling`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmldoc = """
<div class="search-article-title-description">
    <div class="search-article-title">
      <a href="https://www.pga.com/pgapro/info/999918438?atrack=pgapro%3Anone&amp;seapos=result%3A1%3AJeff%20S%20Swangim%2C%20PGA&amp;page=1">Jeff S Swangim, PGA</a>
      <div class="search-article-protitle">
        Assistant Professional
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-article-address">
      <div class="search-instructor-course">
        Lake Toxaway Country Club
      </div>
      4366 W Club Blvd<br>Lake Toxaway, NC  28747-8538<br> 
      <div class="spotlightphone_num">
        (828) 966-4661
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldoc,"html.parser")

addr = soup.find('div', {'class':'search-instructor-course'}).next_sibling.strip()
state_zip = soup.find('div', {'class':'search-instructor-course'}).next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.strip()


print (' '.join([addr, state_zip]))
```

**Output:**

```
print (' '.join([addr, state_zip]))
4366 W Club Blvd Lake Toxaway, NC  28747-8538
```